# Responding to the onmousemove event outside of the browser window in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

In Internet Explorer 7 *body onmousemove* or *document.onmousemove* events only seem to fire while the mouse is inside the browser window, not when it's outside. Yet in Firefox the `onmousemove` event is called correctly when I move outside of the browser window.

How can I setup an event to be called outside of the browser window in IE?

[Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/) does this in IE. If you hold the mouse button down and move the mouse outside of the browser window you can see that the map still moves.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

(Note: this answer refers exclusively to the "standard" drag implementation of `mousedown -> mousemove -> mouseup`. It is not applicable to the [HTML5 drag specification](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html)).

Allowing dragging outside the browser window is an old problem that different browsers have solved in two ways.

With the exception of IE, when a user initiates a drag operation via `mousedown` browsers have done something neat (and this is all just from observation): a kind of statemachine kicks in to handle the special case of mouse movements outside the window:

1. User triggers `mousedown` event inside the `document`
2. User triggers `mousemove` event. Event fires **even when triggered from outside the `document` (i.e. the window)**
3. User triggers `mouseup` event (inside or outside the `document`). `mousemove` events triggered from outside the document **no longer fire**

IE and older versions of Firefox [as late as 2.0.20] don't exhibit this behavior. Dragging outside the window just doesn't work<sup>1</sup>.

The problem for IE and FF2 actually lies in whether an element is "selectable" or not (See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-user-select) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534706(VS.85,loband).aspx)). If a dragging implementation does nothing (thereby allowing selection by the mouse), then said implementation does not have to account for movements outside the window; the browser will go ahead and fire `mousemove` properly and the user is allowed to drag freely outside the window. Nice.

However by letting the browser decide what to do on mousemove you get this effect where the browser thinks the user is trying to "select" something (eg the element), as opposed to moving it, and proceeds to frantically try to highlight the element or text therein as the mouse crosses in or out of the element during the drag.

Most drag implementations I've seen do a little trick to make the element being dragged "unselectable", thereby taking full control of `mousemove` to simulate dragging:

```
elementToDrag.unselectable = "on";
elementToDrag.onselectstart = function(){return false};
elementToDrag.style.userSelect = "none"; // w3c standard
elementToDrag.style.MozUserSelect = "none"; // Firefox
```

This works nicely, **but breaks dragging outside the window**. <sup>2</sup>

*Anyway*, to answer your question, to get IE (all versions) to allow dragging outside the window, use [`setCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536742(VS.85,loband).aspx) (and inversely [`releaseCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536689(VS.85,loband).aspx) when the mouse is released).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Simple drag demo</title>
<style>
#dragme {
  position:absolute;
  cursor:move;
  background:#eee;
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:10px;
}
</style>

<script>
function makeDraggable(element) {

  /* Simple drag implementation */
  element.onmousedown = function(event) {

    document.onmousemove = function(event) {
      event = event || window.event;
      element.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
      element.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
    };

    document.onmouseup = function() {
      document.onmousemove = null;

      if(element.releaseCapture) { element.releaseCapture(); }
    };

    if(element.setCapture) { element.setCapture(); }
  };

  /* These 3 lines are helpful for the browser to not accidentally 
   * think the user is trying to "text select" the draggable object
   * when drag initiation happens on text nodes.
   * Unfortunately they also break draggability outside the window.
   */
  element.unselectable = "on";
  element.onselectstart = function(){return false};
  element.style.userSelect = element.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="makeDraggable(document.getElementById('dragme'))">

<div id="dragme">Drag me (outside window)</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[Demo can be seen here](http://jsbin.com/ifuma#noedit).

This is exactly what Google maps does (as I discovered since reverse engineering google maps back in 2004 when it was first released).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I believe it actually only breaks when initiating a drag operation (i.e. `mousedown`) on a textnode. Element/container nodes do not exhibit the same behavior and can be dragged around inside or outside the document, provided the user moused down on an "empty " portion of the element</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Again, for drag initiations on textnodes.</sub>

Comment: This saved me so much frustration!  IE is the one that needs Capture and has it.  The others properly detect mouseup outside the document.

Comment: Hi Crecent Fresh, I have one case, where whenever there is a `mouseup` following a `mousedown`, an alert should pop up. So, after `mousedown` on the document, if the user drags his mouse out of the window with the mouse still down, and releases it outside the window, the alert should pop up. How do I do it? I didn't much understand your code, since it involves stuff like selection and drag...

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the code here, as it seems to work in IE8 and FF3.5.  If you can understand his code great.
http://www.walterzorn.de/en/dragdrop/dragdrop_e.htm

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty criptic code, but he seems to be using document.onmousemove too, I wonder what the secret is?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't examined the code too much, but you may want to use Firebug on Firefox, or the Web Developer toolkit on IE to watch what is happening as you move the mouse outside the browser.

Comment: Thanks. How would I watch what is happening in Firebug or the Web Developer toolkit on IE while I move the mouse? I've looked all over both of those but don't see any way to watch events.

Comment: Also I notice that in walterzorn.com/dragdrop/dragdrop_e.htm only the images can be moved with the mouse out of the window and not the div example at the bottom. Similarly with Google Maps you are actually dragging an image around, not a HTML element.

Maybe it's a limitation of IE that only the image drag event or something can work outside of the page?

Comment: You can try this, and watch it in the console: console.info("y is greater than x")

Comment: It would be nice to know where the walterzorn.com website ended up, it has been down for a while since July/2010 [ref. http://forums.netobjects.com/showthread.php?9398-Walter-Zorn-s-website-is-down] and it's still down!!!