# Mouse events outside browser

Tags: html, mouseevent, dom-events

Google maps somehow can handle the mouse events when the pointer is outside the window. This feature can bee seen during map dragging.
I try do the same but I can't catch any event when the pointer is outside the browser window.

How to do the mouse handling like in Google maps ?

Don't tell me "it's impossible", just open the Google maps and look at the dragging behavior.

Comment: They're not.  The browser keeps sending drag events, since the click has already been started.  The cursor is effectively inside the browser until the mouse is released, even if it appears outside of it.

Comment: In what way does Google Maps do this? I really don't think it's possible to capture mouse events (with JS) that happen outside the browser..

Comment: Google can do that. Launch google maps and see.

Comment: You can't capture events outside of the browser window unless the window still has focus. I imagine you're talking about being able to drag the map whilst the mouse isn't in the window, but that is as @Brad describes. The event is attached in the window. Can you be more specific as to what event is captured?

Comment: Guys, I see that google DOES . I just need to know the way. Just piece of code or link to the solution,

Comment: It's a disaster - hundred of same questions and no one can tell how to hadnle in google-like way.

Comment: @MadHollander as both Alex and Brad said, it can't be done with JS. It will work on Google maps when trying to drag starting from inside the browser. But not from outside of it. Try it yourself with a smaller browser window. Try to drag starting from outside the map/browser. Also, I don't think something like this will ever be implemented due to the sandbox environment

Comment: Just relax, there is a solution - http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag/demo/contain

Comment: A good answer, including simple jsbin code example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1745382/592125

Comment: Thank's. However, I invented the same solution. But, anyway, thank's :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responding to the onmousemove event outside of the browser window in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685326/responding-to-the-onmousemove-event-outside-of-the-browser-window-in-ie)