# How to detect a MouseUp event outside the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for jQuery solution to detect `mouseup` outside the window. That is, after the mouse has been **downed** inside the window, dragged outside while still down, and then released outside, is when the event should fire.

I tried `document.mouseup = function() {}`, it didn't help. I tried to follow the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685326/responding-to-the-onmousemove-event-outside-of-the-browser-window-in-ie/1745382#1745382), but couldn't properly understand it (I even left a comment asking for help, but no help yet..:( )

Comment: I believe it should be `document.onmouseup`

Comment: Yeah yeah, I mean that actually...:D

Answer (score 7):

I have a website that uses this event and it works as you described:

```
$(window).on('mouseup', function(){
   //your code here
});
```

<s>Note: only tested in jQuery 1.8.3, but it *should* work in 1.9</s>

jsFiddle confirms. Works in jQuery 1.9.1 and 2 beta: http://jsfiddle.net/udRNx/1/

In case you didn't know, this piece of code must be placed in either `$(document).ready(fn)` or `$(window).onload(fn)`.

Comment: Actually, it is not really necessary to wait for DOM ready. The `window` object can be accessed anywhere independent of document readiness, so you can include this code anywhere after the jQuery library.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Should have tried `window` instead of `document`..Looks I have donated my brains to the zoo...:D

Comment: However, I just observed a strange thing. If I `mousedown` anywhere within the document and drag it out with mouse still down such that some element (be it text, or image) is selected (as shown by being highlighted in blue), then `$(document).mouseup()` fires when the mouse is released outside the window. However, the same doesn't work when it is dragged out and released in such a manner that nothing gets selected...

Comment: Apparently `$(window).mousemove(fn)` (as opposed to `$(elem).mousemove(fn)`) also keeps tracking the position outside the window as long as some button was pressed (and held down) while inside the window. This is nice if you want to keep moving objects or whatnot even if pointer goes outside.

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases. Example: https://codepen.io/thdoan/pen/jwLPjL (click image, drag up to the top frame, release).