# javascript: events outside of a window

Tags: javascript, events, mouse

Is it possible to get a mouse event which is fired outside of a browser window? Or is it possible to check if the mouse is pressed when the mouse is moved over a window?

Comment: A good answer for the one way that this is possible (dragging outside of window, like Google maps), including simple jsbin code example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1745382/592125

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, but from this sentence here -

> Or is it possible to check if the mouse is pressed when the mouse is moved over a window

You can check when the page is being focused, so when someone switches back to your page tab.

```
window.onfocus = function() {
   console.log('focus');
   alert('focus'); // See note
};
```

> **Note -**  If you use `alert` in the `onfocus` event the `alert` will popup multiple times.
>   This only happens with `alert` and must be a bug somewhere, maybe someone can shed some light on it.

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wDYbJ/4/)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to see if the mouse is in the window or not. You could do this with a `setInterval` that checks every 300 ms or so to see if the mouse is in the window.

You could also use `mouseout` and `mouseover` events, assuming you can include jQuery.

```
$(document).mouseout(function(){
alert("Mouse not in window");
});
$(document).mouseover(function(){
    alert("Mouse in window");
});
```

Picking up click events and other things outside the browser are not possible.