# How does Google Maps widget detect mouse position and release event outside of its iframe when apparently embedded in crossdomain?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, cross-domain, mouseevent

I am working on an embeddable map widget but I am struggling to detect mouse movement and release events outside of my iframe when my widget is embedded as (multiple nested) iframe in a crossdomain situation.

To my best knowledge such thing should not be even possible - you can not add a listener to window.parent - but Google Maps widget is apparently doing exactly that.

1. Start dragging the map,
2. move your mouse outside of the widget - the map redraws according to your mouse position,
3. release outside of the widget - the map dragging stops.

How are they doing it - across all browsers?

Example: http://jsbin.com/napepohavi/edit?html,output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685326/responding-to-the-onmousemove-event-outside-of-the-browser-window-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

The position of the mouse CAN be detected outside of the frame if and only if user started a drag action inside the frame. Listening to ***mousemove*** on the window element will do the trick:

```
$(window).on("mousemove", function(e) {
    console.log(e.pageX);
});
```

With one condition: the initial ***mousedown*** must be allowed to propagate to the window element. In other words there must be no **preventDefault()** on the ***mousedown*** anywhere in the DOM above the element where the drag started.